# CSS3 animation-play-state paused not working in iPad browsers

Tags: css, ipad, css-animations, mobile-safari

I have a simple `animation` which is working fine on all *devices* and *browsers* except *iPads* (Safari and Chrome).

*Issue:* `animation-play-state: paused` not working in *iPad browsers*.

I've even tried adding `inline styles` directly when inspecting `elements`, but without success.

```js
var btnPause = document.getElementById('buttonPause');
var btnPlay = document.getElementById('buttonPlay');

btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('box').style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  document.getElementById('box').style.animationPlayState = "running";
})

btnPause.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('box').style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
  document.getElementById('box').style.animationPlayState = "paused";
})
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: moveIt 10s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes moveIt {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } 
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveIt {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } 
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id='buttonPlay'>Play Anim</button>
<br><br><br><br>
<button id='buttonPause'>Pause Anim</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wby9h0vd/1/)